# How do I find somebody to review my CV?

Tags: resources, criticism, resume

I've written a CV, and I want to get feedback on it. I want to know I haven't made any mistakes, and that it's as good as I can make it.

But I don't know where to find such a service; what to expect from somebody I hire; how to find somebody I can trust to do a good job; and what to expect in terms of budget.

How should I go about this? Where should I be looking, and what should I be looking for?

Comment: There are services you can pay for. Google [resume writing services](https://www.google.com/search?q=resume+writing+services).

Comment: I've edited to make this more helpful, and less simply a list of websites that may or may not do you any good. Best of luck :)

Comment: Your profile states that you are from Colombia. Are you interested only in how to find a service focusing on the Colombian market?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling not just for the Colombian Market, a general review

Comment: @Standback, exelent job, I need someone like you :)

Comment: @what, as you say there are several services, I want some advices of a trustable and not too expensive web site. Or for example if anybody has had a good exprience in Upwork.com

Comment: I recently saw an answer of peer review web sites.  Look around for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.fiverr.com - but make sure you check out a few people before you hire anyone. Also make sure that the person uses correct English in their profile or you are just hiring someone who has no clue!